How to mock a single file from external package with Jest?
I'm working on a product in Typescript that uses some external package (written  in JS if it matters) via npm. In the test i'd like to mock only one JS file from that package.
How can i do it with Jest?
package.js:
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "@company/product": "1.8.0"
    ...

someFile.ts:
import * as sdk from "@company/product";

I've tried to mock it as follows:
someFile.spec.ts:
...

const prefs: IPrefs = {
  some_property: -1
};

jest.mock(
  "@company/product/sdk/api/prefs.js",
  (): { Prefs: IPrefs } => {
    return {
      Prefs: prefs
    };
  }
);

The original "prefs.js" file from the external package looks as follows:

import ... // i can see in the failed test stack trace

export let Prefs = {
  ...
};

But it's clearly not mocking as i can see the stack trace from the original "prefs.js" that comes in the external package.

I'd suggest that you don't. The internal details should be irrelevant to the thing you're testing.

import * as sdk from "@company/product";


const mockPrefs = {
  some_property: -1
};


jest.mock('@company/product/sdk/api/prefs.js', () => ({
  Prefs: mockPrefs
}));

// Import the module to test after the mock setup
import { someFunctionToTest } from './someFile';

describe('Test someFile', () => {
  it('should use the mocked prefs', () => {
    const result = someFunctionToTest();
    expect(result).toEqual(/* expected result based on mockPrefs */);
  });
});


That's a bit different. It's product file (see someFile.ts) that imports the external package module "../sdk/api/prefs.js". We want to test it in someFile.spec.ts So we don't need to import mocked prefs in the test and use it. It's someFile.ts that needs to start working with mocked file from the external package.


Create a __mocks__ directory adjacent to the node_modules

Inside __mocks__, replicate the directory structure of the package you are mocking.


Inside __mocks__/company/product/sdk/api/prefs.js, define the mock implementation for your function:
export const someFunction = jest.fn(() => {
  // return;
});

Here, jest.fn() creates a mock function that you can control in your tests.

How can i access the mock object to read the actual value in the test?

You can use jest.requireMock to retrieves the mock object and also it will allow you you to access its internal state and configuration.
